# readline() not returning anything even though I've used seek(0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I've written this to do some automated file clean-up on my school folder but the last bit of code at  the bottom isn't returning anything when what I want to get is the year that the folder was made.

right now the terminal is giving me this:

```
Yr 10 Cdate.txt
0
```

where the last line is blank, but it should be `2020`.

code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

folder = r"C:\Users\placeholder\OneDrive\aa.School\Yr 10"
line2 = "Yr 10"

creationtime = os.stat(folder).st_ctime
Ctime = datetime.fromtimestamp(creationtime)

c = line2, " Cdate.txt"
fname = ''.join(c)
d = open(fname, "w")
d.write(str(Ctime))
print(fname)

#checks txt files to see time data
e = open(fname)
print(e.tell())
e.seek(0)
print(e.read(4))
```

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you're not closing the file before trying to read from it again! There's an existing question about that: [Python write to a file returns empty file](/q/18048728/4518341). In the future, making an MRE will help to find the problem faster.

Comment: BTW, best practice for opening files is using `with` like `with open(filename) as f: data = f.read()`. It's covered in the official tutorial [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you so much, I'm not too sure why but closing the file didn't work initially, but after using (with open(fname, "w") as d:) it worked perfectly